# How to make the entire item area of multi-select combobox clickable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I have a multi-select combobox with the below datatemplate

```html
<DataTemplate>
   <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"Content="{BindingTitle}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
</DataTemplate
```

When I click on the checkbox or checkbox text the item in the combobox gets selected , but when click outside the check-box area, I expect it to be combobox item to be selected but to my surprise it is not getting selected.Is it a bug or this the expected behaviour.

Any help on how to make the entire area clickable.

Comment: Not sure whether this is expected or not. But this is how WPF ComboBox control works I think

Comment: Maybe it has no background, so there's nothing to hit-test.  Try setting `Background="Transparent"`.

Comment: @Mike Strobel, not working

Comment: Can you maybe show us a small screenshot with annotations of where you can successfully click, and where you want to but can't?

Comment: @MikeStrobel ,I'm unable to upload link   [ {#} {Select}          ]             #-checkbox , { } -clickable area , blank space non-clickable

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `True` on the wrong element... you should set it to `True` on the collection control instead, as it:

> Gets or sets the horizontal alignment of the control's **content**.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

This *does* work and if it doesn't for you, it's because you must have some other XAML elements getting in the way. Try this really simple example *in a new project*:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Boolean}">
    <CheckBox Content="Hello" IsChecked="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

...

```
SomeCollection = new ObservableCollection<bool>();
SomeCollection.AddRange(new bool[] { true, false, true, true, false };
```

Comment: can you post the combobox style ?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your combobox:

```
 <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
 </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

the item container is responsible for the click outside the item and the value is NOT stretch by default so this should sort it out, maybe some margin on the sides , depends on the style